# Vírgulas em ''por exemplo''

Tags: sintaxe, pontuação, vírgula

A expressão **"por exemplo"** deve ser colocada entre vírgulas? Por quê?

Colocando em contexto, temos duas opções de pontuação:

> 1) O zoológico tem animais ferozes, por exemplo, o leão e o tigre.
>
> 2) O zoológico tem animais ferozes por exemplo o leão e o tigre.

Qual delas seria a correta?

Answer (score 9):

Não e sim.

No teu exemplo, não. Noutros exemplos, sim.

No teu exemplo, eu poria uma única vírgula a separar as duas orações que compõem a frase:

> 3) O zoológico tem animais ferozes, por exemplo o leão e o tigre.

## Para o «por exemplo»

No caso concreto do «por exemplo», pomo-lo entre vírgulas se ele é um elemento por si só, e não o pomos entre vírgulas se *é apenas parte* de outro elemento.
(Chamo-lhe elemento e não oração, porque gramaticalmente [uma oração tem verbo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/divisao-de-uma-frase-em-oracoes/2134).)

É um elemento por si só:

> O Manuel João Vieira, **por exemplo**, já foi candidato à presidência.

Não é um elemento só por si:

> O Manuel João Vieira tem muita presença na vida portuguesa, **por exemplo** já foi candidato à presidência.

## Para todas estas expressões pequenas

### Quando não pomos entre vírgulas

*Não pomos* a expressão entre vírgulas quando ela faz parte da frase, oração, ou elemento em que se insere.
Se retirássemos a expressão, a frase ficava estragada.

#### Exemplo 1

> O zoológico tem animais ferozes, por exemplo o leão e o tigre.

Tornar-se-ia, ao tirar a expressão, uma frase inválida:

> (*) *O zoológico tem animais ferozes o leão e o tigre.*

#### Exemplo 2

> Há vários utilizadores, por exemplo o Jorge, que se sentem incomodados pelas animações do site.

Ficaria uma frase inválida ao retirar *apenas* o «por exemplo».

Mas poderíamos retirar o elemento todo, ou substituir «por exemplo» por «como»:

> - Há vários utilizadores que se sentem incomodados pelas animações do site.
> - Há vários utilizadores, como o Jorge, que se sentem incomodados pelas animações do site.

### Quando pomos entre vírgulas

*Pomos* a expressão entre vírgulas quando ela exprime um aparte, uma nota rápida. Algo que não faz parte da oração ou frase, apesar de estar relacionado.

Tirando essa expressão, a frase mantém-se válida.

### Exemplo 1

Esta frase:

> Mantinha-se[, se lhe retirássemos a expressão,] uma frase válida:

Mantinha-se, se lhe retirássemos a expressão, uma frase válida:

> Mantinha-se uma frase válida:

:)

### Exemplo 2

Nesta frase podemos retirar a expressão:

> Não és o melhor do mundo! O Andre Agassi[, por exemplo,] joga melhor que tu.

### Outros exemplos

Isto aplica-se facilmente a outras expressões:

> - Esta é[, digo eu,] a maneira mais fácil de perceber onde pôr as vírgulas.
> - Ou então[, se preferires,] sirvo-te o assado com sumo de laranja.
> - O primeiro a chegar continua[, no entanto,] a ter de ligar as luzes.

Comment: Como "por exemplo" pode ser uma oração por si só, se não tem verbo?

Comment: Estas regras são da gramática portuguesa, não? Será que a gramática brasileira tem regras iguais?

Comment: @BrunoSchiavo não pode ser uma oração, tens razão. Tenho de rever e re-escrever aquilo.

Comment: @BrunoSchiavo 'Tá feito. Não gosto muito do resultado... não sei o que são, sintaticamente, os dois tipos de «por exemplo». :(

Comment: Existe alguma flexibilidade no uso de certas vírgulas. Vê este ["como por exemplo" no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/virgulas-com-contudo-porem-e-como-por-exemplo/27656). Eu também usaria uma só vírgula ("perigosos, por exemplo") ou até "perigosos; por exemplo" ou "perigosos: por exemplo". As vírgulas marcam normalmente pausas na fala; e neste exemplo a primeira pausa (entre "perigosos" e "por exemplo) é bem mais pronunciada que a segunda; duas vírgulas sugere pausas de igual importância. Se quiseres separar "por exemplo" de "o tigre", que é legítimo, >>

Comment: >> eu escreveira "perigosos; por exemplo, o tigre".

Comment: Concordo, @Jacinto.

Comment: Bela dicas, mas não se usa artigo diante de nome próprio de psssoa. Só se for em linguem informal. Na linguagem formal, o correto é: ''MANUEL''e não '' O MANUEL''

Comment: @ANeves Dou-te um voto para cima por mencionares o Vieira no exemplo :)